# rails contact management webapp design help

Tags: ruby-on-rails

maybe the rails pros here can help me with the software design of a contact management web app.

i want to create Groups, where I can add Contacts to. I thought I generate a Group scaffold and a Contact scaffold with

```
group:references
```

Then I the models to

```
Group: has_many :contacts
Contact: belongs_to :group
```

I also set the routes to

```
resources :groups do
  resources :contacts
end
```

The whole thing should then be accessible over the groups controller, the contact views get included as partials.

Is that the right way? Or would you do it another way?

Thanks + regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a contact to be in only one group at a time, that would be ok. To have a contact in more than one group at a time, I'd recommend a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) association.

```
# group.rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :contacts
  …
end

# contact.rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  …
end
```

You can also use the nested routes bidirectionally e.g.

```
# routes.rb
resources :groups do
  resources :contacts
end

resources :contacts do
  resources :groups
end
```

which would give you both `/groups/15/contacts` and `/contacts/43/groups`.

Comment: alright, thanks! and how can i, e.g. add a contact when i use the /group/1/contacts concept? i tried it, but i can't find out how i can process a form, how i manage to send a form to the contacts controller when rendered as partial in groups. any advice? links?

Comment: A proper form should work wherever you may render it. Do you use the RESTful form helper [`<% form_for @contact %>`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for). It has the ability to automatically find the correct POST url if you are using RESTful routes.